# Pass JS Array to server through $.ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, arrays

Here is my piece of code :

```
    $('#addType').on('submit', function(e) {
        $form = $(this);
        var type = [];
        $(this).find('input[type=number]').each(function() {
            type[$(this).attr('id')] = $(this).val();
        });
        console.log(type);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '<?php echo $this->url(array(), 'addType');?>',
            data: {type: type},
            success: function() {
                $form.find('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled','disabled');
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

As you can see, it builds an javascript array from the `input`s in `form#addType` and send it to a server side script supposed to handle this array. My problem is that no data is passed through `$.ajax({})`.

### UPDATE

It seems that it comes from the values of the array keys that cannot by litteral. If I put an incremented number as key, the array is successfully passed. How come?

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have associative arrays. Arrays can only have numerical indices. Also, why not just use `.serializeArray()`? Just pass the form as a jQuery object and you have your data ready to POST.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the `type` an object, not an array:

```
var type = { };
```

You created `type` as an array (using `[]`). Array is an object, too, so You can add named members to it, which is what You do in Your loop:

```
type['my-item-id'] = xxx;
```

*But* when You add the `type` variable to the Ajax request, jQuery checks that the variable is an array and so it iterates through the `type` as trough an array, so it looks for it's "numerical-indexed" items using `type.length` (which is 0 as You added none):

```
for (var i = 0; i < type.length; i++)
    ... type[i] ...
```

When You create `type` as an Object (using `{}`), jQuery sees that it should iterate over `type` as over an object and does it so and "sees" the "named" items:

```
for (var i in type)
    ... type[i] ...
```

Comment: It works! So data passed to server with Ajax can't be an array? It has to be an object?

Comment: @Steve it can be an array or an object.

Comment: I tried to add the explanation in the answer. Feel free to accept it, thanks! :-)

Comment: @Steve  — No, arrays are fine, but arrays can't have named properties. (Well, they can, but they won't be serialised).

Comment: Many thanks for the explanations. Your answer has been accepted.